# Following Selenium IDE to Python - No such element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

This is my first experience with Selenium and HTML.

I tried to use IDE and then follow "the way" it indicated.
My IDE recorded script says

```
Command | Target
-----------------------------------------------
click   | css=#hamburger-btn
click   | css=div.menu-item.menu-item-selected > span.menu-item-title
click   | css=div.menu-item.menu-item-selected > div.menu-panel-content > div.menu-category-cont > div.menu-category-sub > div.menu-category-sub-item.menu-category-sub-item-selected > span.menu-category-sub-item-title
```

And I tried to implement it this way:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url) #url was defined before
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#hamburger-btn").click()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.menu-item.menu-item-selected>span.menu-item-title").click()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.menu-item.menu-item-selected>div.menu-panel-content>div.menu-category-cont>div.menu-category-sub>div.menu-category-sub-item.menu-category-sub-item-selected>span.menu-category-sub-item-title').click()
```

but I get this "No such element" message/error

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.menu-item.menu-item-selected>div.menu-panel-content>div.menu-category-cont>div.menu-category-sub>div.menu-category-sub-item.menu-category-sub-item-selected>span.menu-category-sub-item-title').click()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 597, in find_element_by_css_selector
return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 966, in find_element
'value': value})['value']
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.menu-item.menu-item-selected>div.menu-panel-content>div.menu-category-cont>div.menu-category-sub>div.menu-category-sub-item.menu-category-sub-item-selected>span.menu-category-sub-item-title"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

GB

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the element you're trying to reach has not loaded properly.
Try adding a wait statement, something along the lines of

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

...

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url) #url was defined before
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#hamburger-btn").click()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.menu-item.menu-item-selected>span.menu-item-title").click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.menu-item.menu-item-selected>div.menu-panel-content>div.menu-category-cont>div.menu-category-sub>div.menu-category-sub-item.menu-category-sub-item-selected>span.menu-category-sub-item-title')))

browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.menu-item.menu-item-selected>div.menu-panel-content>div.menu-category-cont>div.menu-category-sub>div.menu-category-sub-item.menu-category-sub-item-selected>span.menu-category-sub-item-title').click()
```

This is considering this element in fact exists in you page and you're correctly addressing it with your css selector.

Comment: I changed WebDriverWait(driver, 20) in WebDriverWait(browser, 20) and added at the beginning 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
but I get the following error: 
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: This means it did not find the element before the 20 seconds wait running out. Maybe you could come up with your own selection, by **ID** or by **XPATH**. Is the page you're trying to interact with public and could you provide the url for it?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not public... But why should it change by ID or by XPATH? I don't think it is a problem of loading though, I see the button that it should click when it gets stuck.

Comment: Sometimes one type of selector fails, that's why I recommended trying a different one

Comment: Sorry, I tried also the others but nothing changed...:(